# Is Apple allowed to distribute GPLv3-licensed software through its iOS App Store?

Tags: gpl, gpl-3, lgpl, redistribution, apple-app-store

This question is specifically about GPLv3, LGPLv3, and Apple's App Store for iOS devices. Given

1. the additional restrictions Apple imposes on iOS users (i.e. not allowing them to modify and run GPLv3 software or LGPLv3-licensed portions of software without additional conditions or at all), and/or
2. the terms of service Apple users must agree to in order to receive software from the App Store,

Is it legal for Apple to redistribute GPLv3 or LGPLv3 software in the iOS App Store?

The only material I've managed to find about the GPL and Apple is from the early 10s when Apple pulled several GPL-licensed projects from its App Store [2] [3]. However, that incident involved the GPL**v2** and Apples old TOS [4] which apple has since changed [5]. Furthermore, that incident mainly drew focus to Apples's App Store TOS, without sufficient  consideration being given to the fact that Apple is acting as *both* the distributor and the entity imposing additional restrictions on device users.

As of this writing, the FSF's FAQ doesn't seem to include anything that can help answer this question.

1. Removed my reference to GPL's Installation Instructions requirement since it's limited to object code sold with a device.
2. https://www.fsf.org/news/2010-05-app-store-compliance
3. https://www.fsf.org/blogs/licensing/more-about-the-app-store-gpl-enforcement
4. https://static.fsf.org/nosvn/mirrored/apple.com/legal/itunes/us/terms.html
5. https://www.apple.com/legal/internet-services/itunes/us/terms.html

Comment: Is there a specific GPLv3 app that you have in mind? As I recall Apple tried to distribute only GPLv2 components in their Mac OS X system due to licensing restrictions; not sure about things that they put in the app store though.

Comment: @Brandin No, I don't unfortunately. I'm asking this question from the perspective of a developer whose LGPLv3-licensed library is used in an iOS App made by a third party.

Comment: Even if it is allowed by the (L)GPL(3), remember that Apple can set whatever rules it wants for its app store. They can remove your app for any arbitrary reason or no reason.

Comment: Apple can indeed set whatever rules it wants, but they can't infringe on the rights of  (L)GPL software authors by redistributing their software without complying with the terms of the license. This question aims to clarify a few issues regarding Apple's legal standing as a licensee of (L)GPL software.

Comment: If there is something inherent in Apple's app store which makes it impossible to comply with the GPL or LGPL requirements, then it is the responsibility of the application developer not to publish it there. Apple has no obligation to make their app store GPL friendly, for example. They certainly don't need to check for GPL compliance before allowing your app in the app store. The most they probably need to do is respond to a DMCA takedown request in case that the copyright holder complains (in case a developer did violate the license).

Comment: I disagree. As a distributor of GPL software, Apple is necessarily a GPL licensee as specified in section 9 of the GPLv3. Do note that I have not granted apple any other license to redistribute my software.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105970/discussion-between-brandin-and-tenders-mcchiken).

Comment: Are there any additional terms that an App Developer must agree to when they want to upload their app to the store?

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau Very likely, but those terms are between Apple and the iOS developer and cannot affect Apple's relationship with the author of the GPLv3 software; Apple still needs to be licensee to redistribute the copyrighted material.

Comment: @TendersMcChiken: Imagine Content Creator A creates a license agreement that says that anyone who redistributes their IceCreamApp must also distribute physical ice cream with it. iOS developer B submits IceCreamApp to the Apple App Store. I can't imagine that Apple is going to be bound to that license; they'll just take it down when notified they are in violation of a license agreement. Apple presumably requires developers to verify they have the right to distribute, either through their terms of service or explicit affirmation in a submission form.

Comment: It's worth noting that unless the copyright owner considers it to be enough of a problem to sue over it, the question is mostly moot.  And if the copyright owner *does* consider it to be a problem, then the lawsuit would likely be between them and the company or individual that submitted it to the store, as Apple's terms and conditions call themselves a contracted agent of the seller, which is the person who submitted the app to the store.  Thus, to the extent that someone is violating the GPL or LGPL, it would likely be the seller, not Apple.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have no intention of trying to argue with rms about this (or any other GPL-related) issue.  But I think there's an interesting difference between GPLv2 and GPLv3 that gives rise to a new line of approach to the issue.

The previous issue with Apple was, as the OP notes, GPLv2-specific.  GPLv2's handling of additional obligations being placed on distribution is to shut down the right to redistribute, in s7:

> If you cannot distribute so as to satisfy simultaneously your obligations under this License and any other pertinent obligations, then as a consequence you may not distribute the Program at all.

Which led to the suggestion that Apple had no right to distribute GPLv2 software, and the discussions that arose and are documented in the question, *supra*.  GPLv3 takes a more interesting line, in s7:

> If the Program as you received it, or any part of it, contains a notice stating that it is governed by this License along with a term that is a further restriction, you may remove that term.

When GPLv3 software is uploaded to the Apple store, that conveyance is covered by GPLv3.  Apple's standard restrictions are placed on it afterwards; thus the recipient, by GPLv3 s7, may simply ignore them.  An exception may arise when the software is uploaded to Apple by a rightsholder; then an argument can be made that the rightsholder, knowing that Apple will place these conditions on redistribution, has consented to them.  But as long as the upload is done by someone who isn't the rightsholder, and who has no power to consent to additional terms, then the GPL, coming first, takes precedence.

If Apple chooses to redistribute software conveyed to them under the terms of GPLv3 (and I firmly believe that Apple is doing the distribution here, and that arguments of "mere conduit" protection do not apply) then they have consented to the GPL, and their terms, to the extent that they are incompatible with GPLv3, are thus invalidated by GPLv3 s7.

Comment: With Apple being a licensee of the GPLv3, do you have any opinion on Apple's compliance with respect to the last part of section 3?

Comment: In any case, I share your opinion on both Apple's relationship with respect to the license and the consequences such a relationship necessarily entails. One interesting corollary of Apple becoming a licensee is that they surrender their legal right to prevent iOS users from circumventing technological measures (i.e. DRM) to exercise their rights under section 3 of the gpl. I believe this effectively gives developers legal grounds to jailbreak *any* iOS device that runs GPLv3 software. This goes far, far beyond what was allowed by the exemptions made by the Copyright Office for iPhones in 2010

Comment: @TendersMcChiken that is an interesting line of argument, but I think separate from this question.  You could ask it as one, perhaps?

Comment: @TendersMcChiken That is more of a legal question, and it sounds quite dubious. If it were true then I could make up any kind of license with any kind of agreement terms I choose, and then upload software containing that license to the Apple app store, and then when they accept my app I could claim that they are now obligated to adhere to 'our' agreement in my software license. I don't know but I'm pretty sure contracts don't work that way. And besides, this issue is not unique to Apple or the app store at all in any case.

Comment: Please don't argue that supplementary question in this comments field!  I have suggested the OP ask it as a question in its own right.  If (s)he does, we can answer there it in full; if (s)he doesn't, then this is not the place to try to elevate it to being one.

Comment: As suggested by MadHatter, I've reworded the comment into a question and posted it [here](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/9535/does-the-gplv3-give-recipients-the-legal-right-to-circumvent-technological-measu).

Answer (score 12):

I emailed Mr. Richard Stallman, the primary author of the GPL, for his opinion on this issue. I received the following reply:

> I studied this question for a while.  It is clear that that matter of distribution violates GPLv3 overall.  However, I couldn't be sure
>   what courts might say.  To work out the answer would require
>   a very capable lawyer.